# Display 3 dimensions on a 2d plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this csv with three columns: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/moduVSmnc.csv

Which looks like this:

```
modu,apl,mnc
0.30,2.06,51.0
0.30,2.07,45.0
0.30,2.10,35.0
0.30,2.15,48.33
0.30,2.20,35.33
0.30,2.25,34.5
0.30,2.24,28.0
0.34,2.10,44.0
0.34,2.15,47.5
0.34,2.13,31.0
0.34,2.20,36.0
0.34,2.19,32.0
0.34,2.20,49.0
...
```

I'd like to display the variable "modu' on the x axis, "apl" on the y axis, and "mmc" as a colour.

Now, I'd like the plot to be a square grid, like so (sorry for the awful colours...) :

[image]

What's a straight forward way to accomplish this in R with ggplot2?
Using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
fileName = paste("/moduVSmnc.csv", sep = "")
mydata = read.csv(fileName,sep=",", header=TRUE)
ggplot(mydata)+geom_tile(aes(x=modu,y=apl,fill=mnc))
```

Produces something close to what I need:

[image]

Except, I need "modu" and "apl" to fall into bins, so I have a clean grid where all tiles are 1) filled with a colour and 2) side by side with each other.

Comment: http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/
and more see: https://www.google.at/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ggplot%20heatmap

Comment: Thanks! using http://www.xeqtit.com/blog/2012/09/creating-a-heatmap-using-r-project-and-ggplot2#.VF6XHYc7mQs the problem becomes a data format issue. Namely, how to get from my cvs to a matrix-formatted dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
df <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/moduVSmnc.csv")
breaks <- seq(1.95,2.5,by=0.05)
gg <- aggregate(mnc~cut(apl,breaks=breaks)+modu,df,mean)
colnames(gg)<- c("apl","modu","mnc")
gg$modu <- as.factor(gg$modu)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
ggplot(gg) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x=modu,y=apl,fill=mnc))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(brewer.pal(10,"Spectral")))+
  coord_fixed()
```

So this puts the `apl` variable into bins as you say, and then calculates the mean `mnc` for each bin. The `modu` values are already binned. We need to convert both (the binned) `apl` and `modu` to factors and set `coord_fixed(...)` to get square tiles.

Notice that some of the bins are empty...

**EDIT**: Response to OP's comment.

The `cut(...)` function generates labels that show the range in each bin by default. You can change this using the `labels=...` argument, as below.

```
df <- read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/moduVSmnc.csv")
breaks <- seq(1.95,2.5,by=0.05)
gg <- aggregate(mnc~cut(apl,breaks=breaks,
                        labels=format(breaks[-1],nsmall=2))+modu,
                df,mean)
colnames(gg)<- c("apl","modu","mnc")
gg$modu <- as.factor(gg$modu)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
ggplot(gg) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x=modu,y=apl,fill=mnc))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(brewer.pal(10,"Spectral")))+
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh this is so great... Is there a reason why the y axis shows two numbers? Is it possible to only display the second number?
Thanks!